# why we use alter command when kill session in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I use windows 7 and oracle 11g , so when we need to kill session in oracle we use:

```
alter system kill session 'sid','serial#';
```

my question is why we use the command `alter` to do this ??

as i know

> alter command modifies a database or the file and filegroups which are
>   associated with the database.

Comment: @AlexPoole no , i just wonder why alter ? is session state saved in table so thats why we used alter to change its state ?

Comment: Why *not* `alter system`? You're dynamically altering something about the DB instance - in this case the state of a session, with knock-ons to any work it's doing or locks it's holding etc. I'm not sure what you're asking - why the Oracle developers didn't use a separate command like 'kill user' or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you provided is wrong. For killing a session we use [ALTER SYSTEM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2017.htm#SQLRF00902) statement.

You said:

> alter command modifies a database or the file and filegroups which are
>   associated with the database.

Not exactly.

`ALTER` is a [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statement. We can use it for altering *any* object in schema (if we have enough privileges) and even database instances.

So your assumption that  `ALTER` is used for only one or few purposes is wrong.

Comment: thanks i edited it above , but i dont understand why alter ? i mean alter is for change things in db , so here what we change in session so that we use alter ?

Comment: "Use the `ALTER SYSTEM` statement to dynamically alter your Oracle Database instance." The sessions and their processes, memory etc. are [part of the instance](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/startup.htm#CNCPT89031), so why not?

Comment: @AlexPoole , yesss thanks alot now i understand what do you mean , i take alook at this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_2013.htm and i get it , thanks sir .